# How do I use a dictionary in a column of a dataframe to access the values of that column and take the average of another column?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with dictionaries of words and counts in one column and a label in another.

```
|dict                     |label   |
|-------------------------|--------|
|{'word1':1, 'word2':2}   |1       |
|{'word2':4, 'word3':1}   |0       |
|{'word1':3, 'word4':2}   |0       |
|-------------------------|--------|
```

I need an output of all words, their counts, and their average label (weighted by the count):

```
|word   |count  |average|  
|-------|-------|-------|
|word1  |4      |0.25   |
|word2  |6      |0.33   |
|word3  |1      |0.0    |
|word4  |2      |0.0    |
|-------|-------|-------|
```

To clarify the average: for `word1` there is one instance with a label of `1` and three instances on row 3 with a label of `0`, so the average is 1/4 = 0.25.

I am having difficulty with accessing two different columns in the loop. The dictionary is also throwing me off and I'm a bit of a python noob, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. The format of the data is also quite inconvenient for others to use.

Comment: What part of this is your problem? Reading from a DataFrame? Turning a string into an actual dict? Computing the totals and counts for each word based on the data in the input DataFrame? Creating a new DataFrame with the computed results? All these tasks seem fairly straightforward - can you share what you've tried and point out the issues?

Comment: @Grismar, I can loop through and get the first two columns of the output (word, count), but I am lost about getting the average. I am confused about how to access another column during the loop and then to calculate the weighted average.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
##!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'dict': {'word1': 1, 'word2': 2}, 'label': 1},
    {'dict': {'word2': 4, 'word3': 1}, 'label': 0},
    {'dict': {'word1': 3, 'word4': 2}, 'label': 0}])


new_rows = []
count = {}
# lets iter over the rows and keep count of label and value
for row in df.iterrows():
    new = {}
    current_dict = row[1]['dict']
    current_label = row[1]['label']
    for x, y in current_dict.items():

        new[x] = current_label*y

        if x in count.keys():
            count[x] += y
        else:
            count[x] = y
    new_rows.append(new)

# calculate average only when we have full count
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows).sum(axis=0, skipna=True).divide(pd.Series(count))
# append count column to the right
new_df = pd.concat([new_df, pd.Series(count)], axis=1)
# rename the header
new_df = new_df.rename(columns = pd.Series(['average', 'count']))
```

i first restructured the data and then used pandas sum and divide functions to get the average.